# Conflicting constraints with fixed size UIImageView and dynamic height UILabel in self-sizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to create a relatively simple self-sizing `UITableViewCell` with a `UIStackView`. The cell will end up similar to the default `UITableViewCellSubtitle`. It has a `UIImageView` that should be sized exactly 64x64, and next to it, a dynamic-height `UILabel` (`numberOfLines == 0`, dynamic type, `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` set to automatic). The height of the cell should be at least as tall as the `UIImageView`, but taller if the text in the `UILabel` is taller than the `UIImageView`.

This is what the cell *should* look like:
[image: ![How the cell should look]

I'm getting conflicting constraints, and I'm unable to reason why. The UIStackView's `axis` is horizontal, with `alignment` <s>leading</s> top and `distribution` fill. The `UIImageView` has an explicit width and height. The UILabel has no constraints. The `UIStackView` is set to align all four sides to the margins of the `contentView`.

[image: Constraints and conflicts]

If the cell has a static height, things are fine, though I must also manually measure the length of the string in the `UILabel` with `boundingRectWithSize:` and implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. I'd much rather let the view system figure it out for me.

My assumption is that there's something awry with my hugging/compression properties. I have tried setting the `UIImageView`'s hugging and compression resistance priorities to `1000`, because I do not want it to grow or shrink larger than the explicit size I've set. I've tried setting the `UILabel`'s hugging priorities low and compression resistance high, because I want the `UILabel` to be sized exactly as large as the text. I've tried changing the width constraint on the `UIImageView` to be `<=` (not `==`) a value, which removes the ambiguity, but shrinks the `UILabel` to be one line, despite hugging/compression resistance properties. I've additionally tried without the `UIStackView`, and setting the height of the `UILabel` to `>=` the height of the `UIImageView` as well as the bottom of the `UILabel` to the bottom of the `contentView` with similar complications.

---

**Update**: I am using Xcode 9.0b5 under iOS 11. This same situation works as expected under Xcode 8.3.3/iOS 10. In Xcode 9.0b5, I have the "Automatic" checkboxes checked for `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` in the `UIStoryboard`. I've filed this as rdar://33867871

**Update**: Still present in 9.0 GM.

**Update** (11 Dec 2018): Still present in Xcode 10.1, though I just received a message that the bug duped by my bug repoert (rdar://33867871) has been closed. Crossing my fingers for the next release of Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried this at run time? I deleted my answer but just tried this exact setup in code and it works fine. InterfaceBuilder is generally terrible at doing anything with UIStackView so it may be that IB is messing up for you here.

Comment: @Fogmeister You cannot run with the error present in Xcode 9b5. If you uncheck the automatic sizing checkboxes to "eliminate" the error, you get the "unable to satisfy constraints" message. rdar://33867871

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I've opened a similar radar for another UIStackView and InterfaceBuilder thing today too.